# how does the re.finditer loop work?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to fetch email, whatzapp, viber from an instagram API.
I store the downloaded data into a variable called text and check for patterns of email, watzapp, viber numbers ect.

Sample texts:=

```
Recruitment AgentsThe most powerful manufacturers,we have thebest quality.Wechat:13255996580Whatsapp：+8618820784535

 เข้าช้อปทุกวันจ้า ซื้อกับวี้ได้ของแท้แน่นอนค่า แบรนด์อื่นสอบถามได้ค่า ดรีวิว@reviewkayasisshopp LINE ID : @kux1427k (มี @ ด้วยจ้า)

Bags Manufacturer \n✈️ ship worldwide \nTake PayPal/WU\n☎️ phone/whats app: +8613025173183\n☎️ we/chat:2268633046
```

The loop is this:-

```
text=init['bio']
    pattern=r'(?i)([\w.]+@[\w.]+)|(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|whats app|viber|wechat|we/chat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*([‌​()+\d -]+)|\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)|((?:\+\d+)?[ -]?(?:\(\d+\)[ -]?)?[\d -]{6,}\d)'
for mobj in re.finditer(pattern,text):
        if mobj.group(1):
            data1.append(mobj.group(1)) 
        else:
            data1.append('N/A')
        if mobj.group(2):
            t= mobj.group().lower()
            if 'whatsapp' in t:
                data2.append(mobj.group(2))
            if 'viber' in t:
                data3.append(mobj.group(2))
            if 'wechat' in t:
                data4.append(mobj.group(2))
            if 'whats app' in t:
                data2.append(mobj.group(2)) 
            if 'we/chat' in t:
                data4.append(mobj.group(2)) 
        else:
            data2.append('N/A')
            data3.append('N/A')
            data4.append('N/A')         
        if mobj.group(3):
            data5.append(mobj.group(3))
        else:
            data5.append('N/A')
        if mobj.group(4):
            data6.append(mobj.group(4)) 
            print(data6)
        else:
            data6.append('N/A')
```

The problem is when it does not find any of the data which i need i.e email id's , watzapp, line, viber numbers ect, I have given in the loop that the lists should store N/A. Here data1,data2 ect are the python list variables.

how to make the lists store "N/A" when the pattern is not matched?

Comment: First of all, `re.finditer` requires a pattern that matches the text you need. Else, you will get no results. What is the sample text that you are trying to match?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I have edited my question. please have a look. Also, My code is successfully matching the patterns I need. Only in the case where none of the matches are available, it is not storing "n/A" in the lists.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just found out that in case there is no match from the pattern, the control does not even enter into the for loop. So how to write an "if" condition for that?

Comment: Add `if re.search(pattern,text):` and process with `re.finditer` there, then add `else:` and add the logic to add N/As.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much! That worked!  But unfortunately I have another issue within the loop.  Please help me on this too. So here in my code if there are mutilple matches( example-> `The most affordable prices\nD&G,Chanel,Hermes,Miu Miu,Balmain,Dior\nDelivery 2 weeks\n✈Woldwide shipping\n+16166350689; +998909729723` )     In this there are no email, whatzapp or viber contacts but there are 2 Tel numbers. So the Finditer is appending "N/A" to the lists containing watzapp, email ,viber ect. In the first iteration, it gives 1st Tel no and in next, the second. How to stop this

Comment: I want to append the "N/A" to the list only one time in case there are 2 telephone numbers and in each iteration it gives out one

Comment: `if 'N/A' not in data1: data1.append('N/A')`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/Oa8a22) - is it correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct! So I should add this for each one of them. Am i right? Also Is there any way of getting these two Contact numbers `+16166350689; +998909729723` in a single index in the list? Presently it appends as data6[0]=+16166350689 and data6[1]=+998909729723.  Can we store it in a single index example-> data6[0] with a Comma in between `+16166350689,+998909729723`

Comment: Yes, I guess that is what you should do since you are iterating over all matches, and only need to add unique N/A to the lists.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have edited my comment. This is my final question. Wont trouble you more. Thank you

Comment: Oh Sure! Only if you wish to, you can respond. I know I have asked too much!

Comment: As for your comment, why can't you just join the phone numbers later? [`", ".join(data1)`](https://ideone.com/5wIIu5).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Bless you man! I owe you my one day salary. haha! seriously. I am new to python and i was given this pythonic task. Thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: I am not writing Python code every day, but these are things common to all more or less full-fledged languages. Implementation differs, but they are all similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a check if there is a match before running the `re.finditer`:

```
if re.search(pattern, text):
      # go on with finditer
```

Then, when adding `N/A` to the resulting lists, check if the value is already present in the list:

```
if 'N/A' not in data1:
    data1.append('N/A')
```

Here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/Oa8a22):

```
import re
data1 = []
data2 = []
data3 = []
data4 = []
data5 = []
data6 = []
text="The most affordable prices\nD&G,Chanel,Hermes,Miu Miu,Balmain,Dior\nDelivery 2 weeks\n✈Woldwide shipping\n+16166350689; +998909729723"
pattern=r'(?i)([\w.]+@[\w.]+)|(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|whats app|viber|wechat|we/chat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*([()+\d -]+)|\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)|((?:\+\d+)?[ -]?(?:\(\d+\)[ -]?)?[\d -]{6,}\d)'
if re.search(pattern, text):
    for mobj in re.finditer(pattern,text):
        if mobj.group(1):
            data1.append(mobj.group(1)) 
        else:
            if 'N/A' not in data1:
                data1.append('N/A')
        if mobj.group(2):
            t= mobj.group().lower()
            if 'whatsapp' in t:
                data2.append(mobj.group(2))
            if 'viber' in t:
                data3.append(mobj.group(2))
            if 'wechat' in t:
                data4.append(mobj.group(2))
            if 'whats app' in t:
                data2.append(mobj.group(2)) 
            if 'we/chat' in t:
                data4.append(mobj.group(2)) 
            else:
                if 'N/A' not in data2:
                    data2.append('N/A')
                if 'N/A' not in data3:
                    data3.append('N/A')
                if 'N/A' not in data4:
                    data4.append('N/A')         
            if mobj.group(3):
                data5.append(mobj.group(3))
            else:
                if 'N/A' not in data5:
                    data5.append('N/A')
            if mobj.group(4):
                data6.append(mobj.group(4)) 
                print(data6)
            else:
                if 'N/A' not in data6:
                    data6.append('N/A')
print(data1)
print(data2)
print(data3)
print(data4)
print(data5)
print(data6)
```